# Facebook php client

Tags: php, facebook

I'm trying to use facebook connect in my site so users can register/login with it and I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding all the tutorials around the web.

My question is simple, does the facebook php client lib work in my use case or only to develop facebook applications that run inside fb ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know it has been awhile since you posted this but you should definitely try out the new Facebook PHP SDK (can be found [here](http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). With the new Graph API, the implementation of Facebook Connect has become very, very simple.

Comment: This repo is no more.. here's the new repo https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook Connect, you can use JS (as Amar) has suggested. [Here's a tutorial](http://www.pakt.com/pakt/?id=ce00f49ed79e17aa&t=How_to_add_Facebook_Connect_to_your_...) that shows how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://www.pakt.com/pakt/?id=5e17b48f5679ab47) should help you understand easily. I found it useful.

Comment: thx, already read that. they use a modified php client lib.
That's not my question. my question is if the facebook php client is useful in my use case or should I use only the JS lib.

Comment: Ah. If only for login, then Javascript alone should do, I think. Again, you can use the tutorial to just check how he has implemented the login component.